# what is the difference between getTop and getY

Tags: android, view

I don't seem to understand the difference much between getTop() and getY() in android Views. How are they different ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getTop()` returns the y coordinate relative to the parent.

`getY()` returns the y coordinate relative to the parent like `getTop()`, plus the y translation as returned by `getTranslationY()`.

For questions like this it's often helpful to consult the source:

```
public final int getTop() {
    return mTop;
}
```

http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#10644

```
public float getY() {
    return mTop + getTranslationY();
}
```

http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#10908

Answer (score 3):

getY() method return the Y coordinate according to parent.

On other hand getTop() returns the Y coordinate according to its parent view.
If parent has 300 as Y point, and the other view inside of it just a bit lower than it, then returns 100 unlike getY method returns 300+100.

Comment: `gerY()` won't tell you Y-coordinate of view on screen, for that you need to use `getLocationOnScreen()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The doc :

> > [getTop ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop()) : Top position of this view relative to its parent.
> >     Returns The top of this view, in pixels.

And :

> > [getY ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getY()) :The visual y position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to the translationY property plus the current top property.
> >     Returns The visual y position of this view, in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  read the documentation for the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class:

As per my knowledge:

> getX() : The visual x position of this view, in pixels.
>
> getY() : The visual y position of this view, in pixels.
>
> getWidth() : Return the width of the your view.
>
> getHeight() : Return the height of the your view.
>
> getTop() : Top position of this view relative to its parent.
>
> getLeft() : Left position of this view relative to its parent.

Comment: You dont explain confusion, just repeat known definitions.